# How to make corner header cell invisible while keeping the header in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have created a following table in `Qt`.

[image]

I would like to make the cell that says `Checked` invisible. It is possible in `Qt`. I looked online but wasn't able to find anything that would explain it. The explanations that I found only talk about how to make headers visible/invisible.

Is it possible to make this cell invisible? If yes, then how would I do it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to renamed the column from "Checked" to "" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a way to hide a table column's header but I can suggest you to play with roles. For example:

```
QVariant tableModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if(section == 0)
       if(role==Qt::DisplayRole)
           return QVariant();             //returns nothing
       else if(role==Qt::BackgroundRole)
           return QVariant();

       //else if(role==Qt::BackgroundColorRole)   //here you can set your own color
       //    return QColor(qRgb(220,220,220));

    return QAbstractTableModel::headerData(section,orientation,role);
}
```

Or also you can set your own color or gradient that matches your table's background

- If you haven't met MVC before (don't know where to put this code) just read this and everything will be clear : [Model/View Tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/modelview.html)